# Rails ActionText is not rendering styles for the text input box and uploaded attachments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, actiontext

I am trying to use ActionText in my Rails 6 application. I am able to create blobs, but:

1. My text editor does not have any of the default styles

[image: Text editor without styles]
 2. My 'image attachments' look a bit weird when composing a message... but maybe that's normal?

[image: Uploading an image]

3. My blobs don't render with images/attachments (just text styles)

[image: attempting to display the message when the blob is rendered in the view]

I followed the instructions on https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html.

My application.js file looks like this:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")


// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)

//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets

require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
```

My actiontext.scss file looks like this:

```
//
// Provides a drop-in pointer for the default Trix stylesheet that will format the toolbar and
// the trix-editor content (whether displayed or under editing). Feel free to incorporate this
// inclusion directly in any other asset bundle and remove this file.
//
//= require trix/dist/trix

// We need to override trix.css’s image gallery styles to accommodate the
// <action-text-attachment> element we wrap around attachments. Otherwise,
// images in galleries will be squished by the max-width: 33%; rule.

.trix-content {
  .attachment-gallery {
    > action-text-attachment,
    > .attachment {
      flex: 1 0 33%;
      padding: 0 0.5em;
      max-width: 33%;
    }

    &.attachment-gallery--2,
    &.attachment-gallery--4 {
      > action-text-attachment,
      > .attachment {
        flex-basis: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
      }
    }
  }

  action-text-attachment {
    .attachment {
      padding: 0 !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}
```

My application.scss file looks like this:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */

@import "users";
@import "tlks";
@import "spkrs";
@import "shared";
@import "./actiontext.scss";
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";
@import "components/index";
```

My rendering of the relevant areas of the views looks like this:

```
<% @tlk.msgs.each do |msg| %>
  <p class="name-spkr-<%= msg.spkr.id %>"><%= msg.spkr.name %></p>
  <p><%= msg.content %></p>
<% end %>

<% @user_spkrs.each do |spkr| %>
  <% if spkr.hide == false %>
    <%= form_with model: @msg do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :content %>
        <%= f.rich_text_area :content %>
      </div>
      <%= f.hidden_field :tlk_id, :value => @tlk.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :spkr_id, :value => spkr.id %>
      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure what to change to get the styles to be present for both the editor and for the images that are uploaded to render properly.

Thank you for any information.

Edit, in regards to the logs when rendering a page:

```
MiniMagick::Error (You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick installed):

mini_magick (4.10.1) lib/mini_magick/configuration.rb:147:in `cli'
mini_magick (4.10.1) lib/mini_magick.rb:38:in `imagemagick7?'
mini_magick (4.10.1) lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:133:in `executable'
mini_magick (4.10.1) lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:108:in `command'
mini_magick (4.10.1) lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:90:in `call'
image_processing (1.10.3) lib/image_processing/mini_magick.rb:56:in `save_image'
image_processing (1.10.3) lib/image_processing/processor.rb:23:in `call'
image_processing (1.10.3) lib/image_processing/pipeline.rb:50:in `call_processor'
image_processing (1.10.3) lib/image_processing/pipeline.rb:28:in `block in call'
image_processing (1.10.3) lib/image_processing/pipeline.rb:64:in `create_tempfile'
image_processing (1.10.3) lib/image_processing/pipeline.rb:27:in `call'
image_processing (1.10.3) lib/image_processing/builder.rb:13:in `call!'
image_processing (1.10.3) lib/image_processing/chainable.rb:65:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/lib/active_storage/transformers/image_processing_transformer.rb:15:in `process'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/lib/active_storage/transformers/transformer.rb:25:in `transform'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variation.rb:52:in `block in transform'
rails (02ed03172b23) activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:182:in `instrument'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variation.rb:51:in `transform'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variant.rb:105:in `transform'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variant.rb:100:in `block in process'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/lib/active_storage/downloader.rb:15:in `block in open'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/lib/active_storage/downloader.rb:24:in `open_tempfile'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/lib/active_storage/downloader.rb:12:in `open'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/lib/active_storage/service.rb:86:in `open'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:219:in `open'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variant.rb:99:in `process'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/app/models/active_storage/variant.rb:67:in `processed'
rails (02ed03172b23) activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/representations_controller.rb:12:in `show'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:195:in `process_action'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
rails (02ed03172b23) activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:135:in `run_callbacks'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
rails (02ed03172b23) activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
rails (02ed03172b23) activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
rails (02ed03172b23) activesupport/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
rails (02ed03172b23) activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionview/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:192:in `dispatch'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:256:in `dispatch'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:259:in `context'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:253:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:647:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
rails (02ed03172b23) activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (be84e6471c33) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (be84e6471c33) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (be84e6471c33) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (be84e6471c33) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
rails (02ed03172b23) railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
rails (02ed03172b23) activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
rails (02ed03172b23) activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
rails (02ed03172b23) activesupport/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
rails (02ed03172b23) railties/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.0.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
webpacker (c7292e9a1e15) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
rails (02ed03172b23) railties/lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:681:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

UPDATE

Applying Ben Trewern's fix below worked well for the rich text input form.

To solve the images I had to add:

```
gem 'mini_magick
```

and run:

```
$brew install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a similar setup and had a similar issue.  I currently have an application.scss file which starts with:

```
//= require actiontext
...
```

which fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi, this worked in regards to the css of the text input box, but the images are still rendering with the error above (when displaying the blob content).

Comment: Hi, this worked in regards to the css of the text input box, but the images are still rendering with the error above (when displaying the blob content).

Comment: Hi, this worked in regards to the css of the text input box, but the images are still rendering with the error above (when displaying the blob content).